# Cross-referencing an equation reset using setcounter

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, counters

I have to reset equation counter at some point and then reference equations using the new labels but the cross-referencing is not taking the reference to the right location. Here is what I am talking about.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\newcommand{\cotwo}{CO\textsubscript{2}}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
colorlinks=true,
linkcolor=blue,
}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:xas}
\boxed{x_\text{A}^\text{s} = x_\text{A}^\ell \text{e}^{C_1}}
\end{equation}
\[1 - x_\text{A}^\text{s} = (1 - x_\text{A}^\ell) \text{e}^{C_2}\]
Substituting for $x_\text{A}^\text{s}$ from Equation \ref{eq:xas}.
\[1 - x_\text{A}^\ell \text{e}^{C_1} = (1 - x_\text{A}^\ell) \text{e}^{C_2}\]
\setcounter{equation}{0}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:dlnsdT}
\cfrac{\partial \ln \text{s}}{\partial T} = \cfrac{\partial}{\partial T}\left[\cfrac{\mu_\text{\cotwo}^\text{v} - \mu_\text{\cotwo}^\ast}{RT}\right]
\end{equation}
Substituting in Equation \ref{eq:dlnsdT}, we get
\end{document}
```

In the second reference, I want to refer to the equation right above, not the top equation. Does someone know what's wrong with the cross-referencing here or am I missing something obvious?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You get an _error_ from the duplicate equation `destination with the same identifier (name{equation.0.1}) has been already used, duplicate ignored` If you really want two equation (1) then you will need to give different unique labels for hyperref to use as anchors see hypperref package doc

Answer (score 1):

David Carlisle already provided some explanation, here is a way to manipulate the hyperanchor which is basically generated from the corresponding macro `\theHequation` by counting the total numbers of equations and appending the current total number of equations to the expansion of `\theHequation`.

The counting is done with my `xassoccnt` package and associating the `totalequations` counter to the real `equations` counter.

This way unique anchor names are used, as long as no one changes the value of `totalequations` directly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{xassoccnt}
\newcommand{\cotwo}{\ce{CO2}}

%%CO\textsubscript{2}}

\newcounter{totalequations}
\DeclareAssociatedCounters{equation}{totalequations}%


\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
colorlinks=true,
linkcolor=blue,
}


\let\theOldHequation\theHequation
\renewcommand{\theHequation}{\theOldHequation::\number\value{totalequations}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:xas}
\boxed{x_\text{A}^\text{s} = x_\text{A}^\ell \text{e}^{C_1}}
\end{equation}
\[1 - x_\text{A}^\text{s} = (1 - x_\text{A}^\ell) \text{e}^{C_2}\]
Substituting for $x_\text{A}^\text{s}$ from Equation \ref{eq:xas}.
\[1 - x_\text{A}^\ell \text{e}^{C_1} = (1 - x_\text{A}^\ell) \text{e}^{C_2}\]
\clearpage
\setcounter{equation}{0}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:dlnsdT}
\cfrac{\partial \ln \text{s}}{\partial T} = \cfrac{\partial}{\partial T}\left[\cfrac{\mu_\text{\cotwo}^\text{v} - \mu_\text{\cotwo}^\ast}{RT}\right]
\end{equation}
Substituting in Equation \ref{eq:dlnsdT}, we get \dots however in \ref{eq:xas} there is an equation with the same number!
\end{document}
```